# Why is Azure Deployment Center not showing all repos I have in GitHub

Tags: azure, appservice

I'm trying to deploy code to Azure (a .NET web API) but I can't access all the repositories in my GitHub account. I have a lot of repos (>100) and about 80+ of them are public.

However this should not prevent Azure from showing all my repos in the dropdown menu. I am stuck and not sure what the problem is, short of calling Azure themselves to ask. Has anyone experience this and know the reason why Azure does not show all repos in the dropdown menu?

Comment: Please share the screenshot of yout deployment center in portal.

Comment: Disconnect and reconnect it again.

Comment: You need to Re-Authorize and revoke the Azure App Service in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes it happens, Even I have faced this situation once.

You can also see the message in the Deployment Center UI.

[image]

For this you need to revoke the Azure App Service in GitHub.

Navigate to `GitHub` => `Settings` => `Applications` => `Authorized OAuth Apps` => `Azure App Service`.

Click on `Revoke`

[image]

[image]

- Now check the `Deployment Center` in Azure App Service. You will find an option to `Authorize` the GitHub.

  [image]

Click on it. You can see the permissions to the repos.

[image]

Also refer [MSDoc](https://docs.github.com/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories) for the same issue.

> [If you can’t find an organization or repository, you might need to enable more permissions on GitHub.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github%2Cgithubactions#option-1-use-app-service-kudu-build-server:%7E:text=If%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20find%20an%20organization%20or%20repository%2C%20you%20might%20need%20to%20enable%20more%20permissions%20on%20GitHub.)